# Excel to json in java

Tags: java, json, spring, apache-poi

Is there any ready function to convert a excel to json in java? I have investigated use of Apache POI, but it loops through the worksheet, rows and then creates a list out of it and then converts it to json.

Comment: Other than the method you mention not that I know of. Nothing will take a file or reader and convert it directly to a json string

Comment: As there isn't a standard JSON representation of an Excel file, you'll need to write some code anyway to convert things into whatever structure you need in your JSON

Comment: If you share an example of the xls file and the expected json, you might get some advice on how best to proceed

Comment: there are plenty of examples taking excel and converting to csv - those could be modified to output json - eg https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/examples/ss/ToCSV.java and https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/examples/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java